# Lifting property for proper morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be a complex affine variety and $\tilde{X} \to X$ a surjective proper morphism where $\tilde{X}$ smooth. Is it true that every morphism $\mathbb{C} \to X$ can be lifted to $\mathbb{C} \to \tilde{X}$?

I'm particularly interested in the case where $X$ has an isolated singularity and $\tilde{X} \to X$ is a resolution.

Comment: In the isolated singularity case, there is no problem. If you base change, you get a proper morphism $Y\to \mathbb{C}$, which has a section outside finitely many points of $\mathbb{C}$. Take the closure of the image, $Z$. Then $Z\to\mathbb{C}$ is a proper birational morphism and since $\mathbb{C}$ is a smooth curve, this is an isomorphism.